# In R, how do I evaluate an expression in a specific environment within a function?

Tags: r, namespaces, environment

In my apparent naievety, I assumed that when one calls `eval` and specifies an environment (`envir`), the expression (`expr`) is evaluated in that environment.

However :-)

This works as expected:

```r
xx <- 10
nn <- 20
exprs <- binom.test(x=xx,n=nn)
eval(exprs);
```

By default, `eval` evaluates in `parent.frame()`, which the help reveals is *[t]he parent frame of a function evaluation is the environment in which the function was called.*

So in the above example, this is the global environment, where indeed, `xx` and `nn` are defined. So far, so good.

```r
newEnv <- new.env();
assign('xxx', 10, envir = newEnv);
assign('nnn', 30, envir = newEnv);
exprs2 <- expression(binom.test(x=xxx,n=nnn));
eval(exprs2, envir=newEnv);
```

This also works as expected; `xxx` and `nnn` are defined in the `newEnv` environment, and `binom.test` is evaluated in that environment.

Now we wrap this in a function (the one I'm trying to build - I'm building it using the `pwr` package, but for this example I'm using `binom.test` because it's base R and it still doesn't work :-)

```r
loopFunction <- function(expr,
                         ...) {

  ### Get all 'dots' in a named list
  arguments <- list(...);
  argNames <- names(arguments);

  if (any(length(tail(arguments, -2) > 1))) {
    stop("Only the first two arguments may have length > 1!");
  }

  for (esIndex in seq_along(arguments[[1]])) {
    for (pwrIndex in seq_along(arguments[[2]])) {
      tempEnvironment <-
        new.env();
      assign(argNames[1], arguments[[1]][esIndex],
             envir = tempEnvironment);
      assign(argNames[2], arguments[[2]][pwrIndex],
             envir = tempEnvironment);
      if (length(arguments) > 2) {
        for (i in 3:length(arguments)) {
          assign(argNames[i], arguments[[i]],
                 envir = tempEnvironment);
        }
      }
      print(argNames);
      print(as.list(tempEnvironment));
      print(ls(tempEnvironment));
      print(get('x', envir=tempEnvironment));
      print(get('n', envir=tempEnvironment));
      return(eval(expr = expression(expr),
                  envir = tempEnvironment)$estimate);
    }
  }
}
```

When running this, you get:

```r
loopFunction(binom.test(x=x,n=n), x=c(10,20), n=c(30, 100));

#> [1] "x" "n"
#> $x
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> $n
#> [1] 30
#> 
#> [1] "n" "x"
#> [1] 10
#> [1] 30
#> Error in binom.test(x = x, n = n): object 'x' not found
```

So, that error stumps me. clearly, `x` and `n` exist in `tempEnvironment`; and `tempEnvironment` is passed to `eval`.

Why does this suddenly no longer work? Does this work differently inside functions? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You may want to look into `?environment`.

Comment:  Any specific part of that page? I did study that, but can't find (or derive) why `eval(expr = expression(expr), envir = tempEnvironment)$estimate;` should fail in the above example?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but have you tried to run `loopFunction("binom.test(x, n)", x=10, n=30)` with `eval(expr=parse(text=expr), envir =tempEnvironment)$estimate)` replacing the last part of your code? Also, `data.frame[esIndex, pwrIndex]` isn't a valid piece of code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the data.frame was a sloppy edit while making the original code self-contained and more generic. I'll fix the question. Thanks for pointing this out! The 'real' code that we'll use is at https://gitlab.com/openuniversity/study-planning-sample-size/snippets/1856192, in case anybody's interested!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why `expression()` doesn't work in this context. However, it works if you write `expr` as a string and replace `expression(expr)` by `parse(text=expr)`:

```
loopFunction <- function(expr,
                         ...) {

  ### Get all 'dots' in a named list
  arguments <- list(...);
  argNames <- names(arguments);

  if (any(length(tail(arguments, -2) > 1))) {
    stop("Only the first two arguments may have length > 1!");
  }

  for (esIndex in seq_along(arguments[[1]])) {
    for (pwrIndex in seq_along(arguments[[2]])) {
      tempEnvironment <-
        new.env();
      assign(argNames[1], arguments[[1]][esIndex],
             envir = tempEnvironment);
      assign(argNames[2], arguments[[2]][pwrIndex],
             envir = tempEnvironment);
      if (length(arguments) > 2) {
        for (i in 3:length(arguments)) {
          assign(argNames[i], arguments[[i]],
                 envir = tempEnvironment);
        }
      }
      print(argNames);
      print(as.list(tempEnvironment));
      print(ls(tempEnvironment));
      print(get('x', envir=tempEnvironment));
      print(get('n', envir=tempEnvironment));
      return(eval(expr=parse(text=expr), envir =tempEnvironment)$estimate)
    }
  }
}

loopFunction("binom.test(x, n)", x=10, n=30)
```

Result:

```
> loopFunction("binom.test(x, n)", x=10, n=30)
[1] "x" "n"
$`x`
[1] 10

$n
[1] 30

[1] "n" "x"
[1] 10
[1] 30
probability of success 
             0.3333333
```

Comment: That's it, excellent!

And by replacing `expr = expression(expr)` in the original function with `parse(text=substitute(deparse(expr)))`, the expression can be passed as expression (i.e. not as a string).

Still, this behavior seems to be at odds with R's normal 'lazy evalution'. Maybe promises also encapsulate their original environment? So they *are* evaluated later, but not in the environment where that evaluation is prompted?

In any case, thank you very much, this solves it!!!

Comment: I have no idea why your original code did not work to be honest. If you find out why, let us know with an update. Thanks

Comment: I will. I'm equally perplexed. Must be some logical reason somewhere; perhaps @jay.sf knows it, but if not; if I find out, I'll share it here!